# How to test my scrapy method with unitest class

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I want to try some method in my spider.
For example in my project, I have this schema:

```
 toto/
├── __init__.py
├── items.py
├── pipelines.py
├── settings.py
├── spiders
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── mySpider.py
└── Unitest
    └── unitest.py
```

my `unitest.py` look like that:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                           
import re
import weakref
import six
import unittest
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from unittest.case import TestCase
from toto.spiders import runSpider

class SelectorTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    sscls = Selector

    def test_demo(self):
    print "test"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and my `mySpider.py`, look like that:

```
import scrapy

class runSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['http://blog.scrapinghub.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.css('ul li a::attr("href")').re(r'.*/\d\d\d\d/\d\d/$'):
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), self.parse_titles)

    def parse_titles(self, response):
        for post_title in response.css('div.entries > ul > li a::text').extract():
            yield {'title': post_title}
```

In my unitest.py file, How I can call my spider ?
I tried to add `from toto.spiders import runSpider` in my unitest.py file, but but it does not...
I've got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "unitest.py", line 10, in
>   
>       from toto.spiders import runSpider ImportError: No module named toto.spiders

How I can fix It?

Comment: *"but but [sic] it does not..."* - what? Please be more specific about what is happening. Note that the tests directory would generally be *outside* the top level of your package - see e.g. http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/

Comment: where  is runSpider?

Comment: And have you actually *installed* `toto` for the current interpreter? Does `import toto` work anywhere?

Comment: try : 
from toto.spiders.mySpider import runSpider

Comment: My spider work anywhere

Comment: `from toto.spiders.mySpider import runSpider ` launch this error ` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unitest.py", line 10, in <module>
    from toto.spiders.mySpider import runSpider 
ImportError: No module named toto.spiders.mySpider`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '../..')) #2 folder back from current file

from spiders.mySpider import runSpider
```

Comment: Hacking `sys.path` at runtime suggests you're doing something wrong.

Comment: so whats the alternative?

Comment: Actually *installing* the package, in development mode if it's still a work in practice, so that you can test it as it would appear on CI/client installation without the dependency on relative directory positions.

Comment: No, I would write a `setup.py` then `python setup.py develop` to install the package in development mode (preferably in a `virtualenv`).